# Customize stacked bar chart in Plotly

Tags: python, group-by, plotly, bar-chart, visualization

How can I make a solid color fill for bars, without gap? Now I group the x-axis by month and get a non-uniform color. Is it possible to fix it?

I use the [Superstore Sales](https://public.tableau.com/app/learn/sample-data) dataset from Tableau datasets catalog. My code:

```python
fig = go.Figure()

for i in df['region'].unique():
    fig_add = fig.add_trace(
                    go.Bar(
                        x=df['order_date']
                        ,y=df.loc[df['region'] == i, 'sales']
                        ,name=i
                        ,xperiod='M1'
                        ,xperiodalignment='middle'))

fig_add = fig.update_layout(
            height=800
            ,width=1750
            ,title_text="Sales dynamic by region"
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 26
                ,'color' : '#71797E'
                ,'family' : 'Arial'
                }
            ,barmode='stack'
            ,plot_bgcolor='#F3F2F2')
fig.show()
```

I get this result:

[image: my plot]

Answer (score 2):

The reason there are "gaps" is because when you have month on the x-axis, there will be multiple rows in your dataframe with the same region and same month, and plotly will not automatically sum them but instead try to plot all of them and use gaps to between different rows (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#stacked-vs-grouped-bars)).

I think you probably want to create a new column called `order_month` keep track of the month and year (by rounding down the order dates to the 1st of the month), then [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `order_month` and `region` and sum up `quantity` within each group.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel('sample_superstore.xls')
df.columns = [col.lower().replace(" ", "_") for col in df.columns]

df['order_month'] = df['order_date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
df_bar = df.groupby(['order_month','region']).agg({'quantity':'sum'}).reset_index()

fig = px.bar(
    df_bar,
    x='order_month',
    y='quantity',
    color='region',
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
    width=1750,
    title_text="Sales dynamic by region",
    title_font={
        'size' : 26,
        'color' : '#71797E',
        'family' : 'Arial'
    },
    barmode='stack',
    plot_bgcolor='#F3F2F2'
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply! I used this method, but I wanted to find an opportunity to plot a graph without preprocessing the data. The desired result was achieved using `go.Histogram`.

```
fig = go.Figure()

regions = df['region'].unique()

for i in range(len(regions)):
    fig_add = fig.add_trace(
                go.Histogram(
                    x=df.loc[df['region'] == regions[i], 'order_date']
                    ,y=df.loc[df['region'] == regions[i], 'sales']
                    ,histfunc='sum'
                    ,name=regions[i]
                    ,xbins={
                        'size' : 'M1'
                        }
                    ,opacity=0.6))

fig_add = fig.update_layout(
            barmode='stack'
            ,height=800
            ,width=1750
            ,title_text="Sales dynamic by region"
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 26
                ,'color' : '#71797E'
                ,'family' : 'Arial'
                }
            ,plot_bgcolor='#FFFFFF'
            ,xaxis_title=None
            ,yaxis_title=None
            ,legend={
                'orientation' : "h"
                ,'title_text' : 'Category:'
                ,'yanchor' : "bottom"
                ,'xanchor' : "right"
                ,'y' : 1
                ,'x' : 1
                }
            ,bargap=0.2)

fig_add = fig.update_xaxes(
            ticklabeloverflow='hide past domain'
            ,rangeslider_autorange=True
            ,rangeslider_thickness=0.05)

fig_add = fig.update_traces(
            marker_line_width=1
            ,marker_line_color='#F2F1F1')

fig_add.show()
```

My chart
[image: My chart]